# User-Created Header Causing C2061: Syntax Error : Identifier 'classname'

Tags: c++, syntax-error

So, I sort of expect this to end up being a simple answer, but I've been hacking at it for a while now, and can't seem to fix this issue. So I have a particular class, `Intersection`, that when included in any other header gives me:

`error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Intersection'`

This is my Intersection header:

```
#ifndef INTERSECTION_H
#define INTERSECTION_H

#include "Coord.h"
#include "Road.h"
#include "TrafficLight.h"

class Intersection {
private:
    int id;
    Coord * midPoint;
    Road * northRoad;
    Road * eastRoad;
    Road * westRoad;
    Road * southRoad;
    TrafficLight * trafficLight;
public:
    Intersection(int, Coord *, Road *, Road *, Road *, Road *);
    ~Intersection();
    void transitionTrafficLight();
    int getId();
    Road * getNorthRoad();
    Road * getEastRoad();
    Road * getWestRoad();
    Road * getSouthRoad();
    TrafficLight * getTrafficLight();
};

#endif
```

Now, if I attempt to use this class elsewhere, I get the error. For example:

```
#ifndef ROAD_H
#define ROAD_H

#include "Coord.h"
#include "Intersection.h"
#include <string>

class Road {

public:
    enum LaneCount { TWO_LANE = 2, FOUR_LANE = 4 };
    Road(std::string, Coord *, Coord *, LaneCount, Intersection *, Intersection *, int);
//shortened
```

Particularly at the `Road` constructor (and any other classes which reference `Intersection`). I don't think it's a syntax problem, as `Coord` is another class, defined in the same manner, and the compiler (VS 2008) doesn't complain about it. It's just `Intersection` in particular that's giving me this trouble. :/

I'm tagging it homework -- it's what it's for, even though this is just an error I can't get rid of rather than part of the problem.

Thoughts?

Comment: It looks like you need to forward declare `class Intersection;` in the ROAD_H file.

Comment: Interesting. That seems to have done it. Could you explain why that works while including the entire header does not, and why only that class would seem to have a problem? Do it in an answer and I'll gladly give you the check. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It looks like the error is that you have two header files that are circularly including one another - intersection.h and road.h.  Doing this tends to lead to weird surprises in C++ because of how include guards work.  For example, suppose that I have two header files that look like this:

```
// File: A.h
#ifndef A_Included
#define A_Included

#include "B.h"

class A {};

void MyFunction(B argument);
#endif
```

and

```
// File: B.h
#ifndef B_Included
#define B_Included

#include "A.h"

class B {};

void MyOtherFunction(A argument);
#endif
```

Now, if I try to `#include "A.h"`, then it expands out to

```
// File: A.h
#ifndef A_Included
#define A_Included

#include "B.h"

class A {};

void MyFunction(B argument);
#endif
```

When I try expanding out the `#include "B.h"`, I get this:

```
// File: A.h
#ifndef A_Included
#define A_Included

// File: B.h
#ifndef B_Included
#define B_Included

#include "A.h"

class B {};

void MyOtherFunction(A argument);
#endif

class A {};

void MyFunction(B argument);
#endif
```

At this point, the preprocessor will again try expanding out `A.h`, which leads to this:

```
// File: A.h
#ifndef A_Included
#define A_Included

// File: B.h
#ifndef B_Included
#define B_Included

// File: A.h
#ifndef A_Included
#define A_Included

#include "B.h"

class A {};

void MyFunction(B argument);
#endif

class B {};

void MyOtherFunction(A argument);
#endif

class A {};

void MyFunction(B argument);
#endif
```

Now, let's see what happens when we resolve all of these weird include guards.  The first time we see A, it's expanded out, as is the case when we expand out B for the first time.  However, when we see A for the second time, it's not expanded out at all.  Thus, after taking out comments and preprocessor directives, we get this resulting code:

```
class B {};
void MyOtherFunction(A argument);
class A {};
void MyFunction(B argument);
```

Notice that when `MyOtherFunction` is declared, `A` has not yet been declared, and so the compiler reports an error.

To fix this, you can forward-declare `A` and `B` in the header files that need them:

```
// File: A.h
#ifndef A_Included
#define A_Included

class A {};
class B;    // Forward declaration

void MyFunction(B argument);
#endif
```

and

```
// File: B.h
#ifndef B_Included
#define B_Included

class B {};
class A;    // Forward declaration

void MyFunction(B argument);
#endif
```

Now, there are no more circular dependencies.  As long as you `#include` the appropriate header files in the .cpp files, you should be fine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Damn! This is a great answer as well; thanks for going in-depth on it. I'm incredibly rusty at C++ (been focusing on Java), so this is a nice refresher. Thank you!

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you.